# Run cucumber tests in a serial fashion in Java

Tags: java, cucumber

I have a number of cucumber .feature file written in Java.

It looks like they are running in parallel.

How do I run the cucumber tests one by one in a single threaded fashion?

The run test config is:

```
@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(strict = true, 
        glue = "com.myproject.steps", 
        features = "classpath:cucumber/features/", 
        format = { "pretty", "html:target/report/cucumber",
                "json:target/report/cucumber/cucumber.json" })
public class RunIntegrationTest {
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using Junit and junit not have such parallel execution functionality

Another thing is cucumber cucumber-jvm-parallel, are you using it?

Does you have multiple TestRunner java file with `CucumberOptions` in `src.test.java` package, if so keep one class file only